# Standalone minion to Master minion

Tags: salt-stack

I have a host with standalone minion configured. It has all the required configurations in /srv/salt. Executing it using `salt-call`, and it works as expected. Now I wanted have a master to have control over this minion.

So I have created a salt master in one another host, and updated the /etc/salt/minion configuration file in the minion host to connect to master.Then restarted the minion and accepted key in server.

Now I could do some basic checks like `salt 'minion-host' test.ping` . But `salt 'minion-host' state.highstate` is failing with minion not responding. I could I execute the minion with its configuration from the master.

What is the proper way to execute the salt-call over minion, using the available minion configurations inside minion host.

Answer (score 0):

If `salt minion test.ping` works that's a good start, you could also use:

```
salt-run manage.up
```

That should give a list of minions currently up.

Keep in mind that the minion needs to run the salt agent (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/system/communication.html)

Test with this:

```
salt minion state.highstate test=True
```

Or get a more verbose output using:

```
salt minion state.highstate -l debug
```